# WebRTC routing using TURN without exposing IP address to peers

Tags: webrtc, turn, coturn

I'm searching for a way to implement client to client communication without the peers knowing each others IP addresses. Using WebRTC with TURN (looking at [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn)) would be ideal, for the clients already supporting the protocol. But reading from the [TURN specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5766) it states:

> the client MUST include an XOR-PEER-ADDRESS attribute and a DATA attribute. The XOR-PEER-ADDRESS attribute contains the transport address of the peer to which the data is to be sent.

So it seems that the protocol dictates having the peer IP. Optimally for me this attribute could be a provided (anonymous) key which I could map to an IP on the TURN server in a routing table. Updating the routing table would be handled by the signaling server.

Is there something out there supporting functionality like this, or should I plan on writing the clients and the TURN functionality myself? In my case all the traffic would of course be routed through a TURN server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User coTURN and set `iceTransportPolicy` option to `relay` (deafult is `all`), then peerConnection will generate only `relay candidates(TURN)`.
So media will flow via TURN server only.
And peers won't aware of remote users IP(Reflex/Host).

Create peerConnection as fllowing

```
var iceServers = [{"urls":["turn:TURN_IP:3478?transport=udp"],"username":"TURN_USERNAME","credential":"TURN_PASWD"}];
var config = {"iceServers": iceServers, "iceTransportPolicy": "relay"};
var constraints = [{"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement": true}];
pc = new RTCPeerConnection(config, constraints);
```

Comment: By using this I am able to route all the traffic through the turn server, but for example the send indication includes the peer ip in the XOR-PEER-ADDRESS, so as far as I see this won't work.

Comment: Ok, It does seem you're right, when relaying the traffic through the turn server the XOR-PEER-ADDRESS contains the TURN server IP. Thanks for the answer!